# Thickness of math arrows

Tags: tikz-arrows, dimensions

I'm making a poster with `a0poster` and `pxfonts` package for math fonts.

I'm using `tikz-cd` for diagrams and I'm adjusting the line width for arrows and the arrow tips with

```
\tikzcdset{arrows={line width=1pt},arrow style=math font}
```

As you can see on the image below, although the arrow tips coincide, the line width does not fit the width used in math arrows (compare with `\to`).

[image]

What is the value used for lines in arrows? What should I use in `line width`?

Comment: Have you tried this -- `\tikzset{
commutative diagrams/.cd,
arrow style=tikz,
diagrams={line width=2pt}}`  % change 2pt to your need

Comment: I want to use that arrow tip and I'd like to use the right value instead of making tests.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's an option just for that: `line width=rule_thickness`

[image: comparison of to and tikzcd arrows]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pxfonts}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\tikzcdset{arrows={line width=rule_thickness},arrow style=math font}

\begin{document}

$A \to B$ \begin{tikzcd} A \arrow[r] & B \end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Ow, I saw that on documentation but I didn't know that it would be automatically adjusted according to the font size. Thanks.